# Scrolling WITHIN a div using it's ref?

Tags: reactjs, scroll, drag-and-drop

I was wondering how could I programmatically scroll INSIDE a div using its ref ? Here's the idea we have to achieve:

I use react-trello to show a 'kanban' board. I want to be able to scroll from left to right on a press of a button. So if you load the page, it's initially showing the left most card. Everytime we click on this button I would like to scroll X amount to the right.

I tried attaching a ref to the  component from react-trello and use ref.current.scrollTo({x:50}) for testing purposes. However it does not scroll '50' to the right.

Am I missing something ?

```
        <div>
            <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                <Icon>prev</Icon>
                <Icon onClick={() => {
                        board.current?.scrollTo({ x: 100 })
                    }}>
                    next
                </Icon>
            </div>
            <Board
                ref={board}
                style={{ background: 'none' }}
                components={{ Card: CustomCard }}
                data={data}
                editable={false}
                draggable={false}
                laneDraggable={false}
                cardDraggable={false}
                hideCardDeleteIcon={true}
            />
        </div>
```

Comment: 1. Is the `onClick` working? (test with a console log). 2. Does `Board` have `forwardRef`? (otherwise ref passed to a component wouldn't work)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is that you are trying to set a constant instead to `x` instead. Instead, you can use [scrollLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft) property of Board component and use that as a reference. Also you have to use use `left` instead of `x`.

Therefore if you replace `board.current?.scrollTo({ x: 100 })` with `board.current?.scrollTo({ left: board.current?.scrollLeft + 50 })`, you should be fine.